# Show that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

> Let $S$ be the set of all subsets of $\mathbb{Z}$. Define a relation $\sim$ on $S$ via $T \sim  U$ if and only if $T \setminus  U $ and $U\setminus  T$ are both finite. Show that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation and describe $[\{1, 2, 3\}]$ and $[\{. . . ,−4,−2, 0, 2, 4, . . .\}]$.

**My attempt**.

Reflixivity: Since $U\setminus U=\emptyset $, we have that $U\sim U$.

Symmetry: If $T \sim  U$ , then $T \setminus  U $ and $U\setminus  T$ are both finite. Thus $U \sim  T$

Trnsitivity: (Here my problem begins) If $T \sim  U$ and $U \sim  V$, we have that $T \setminus  U,\; U \setminus  T,\;  U \setminus  V $ and $V \setminus  U $ are all finite. How can I relate $T$ to $V$?

On the other hand, I think that the elements of $[\{1, 2, 3\}]$ are all elements of finite cardinality, since their differences will always be finite. Whereas for the elements of $[\{. . . ,−4,−2, 0, 2, 4, . . .\}]$ I have no idea.

Comment: Hint for transitivity: you can show that $T\setminus V$ is a subset of the union of some of the sets you wrote.

Comment: As for the elements who are related to $\{\dots,-4,-2,0,2,4,\dots\}$, those would be the sets of integers who have all the even numbers except at most a finitely many and at most a finite number of odd numbers.  This generalizes... $[X] = \{(X\setminus X^-)\cup X^+~:~X^+\subseteq X,~|X|<\infty,~X^-\subseteq X^c,~|X^-|<\infty\}$ (*where here I used square brackets for 'equivalence class of' and I used bars for 'cardinality of'*)

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you very much, I will analyze that answer to fully understand what you are saying. One question, Are the rest of things okay? (except transitivity).

Comment: @player3236 If I take the union of $T \setminus U$ with any other of the subsets that I wrote, this guarantees that $T \setminus V$ is contained in that union and since the union of finite sets is finite and its subsets as well,$T$ is related to $V$. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. However, to save your time, only consider $T\setminus V \subseteq (T\setminus U) \cup (U \setminus V)$.

Comment: @JMoravitz When you write $X^+$ do you mean positive numbers or even numbers? (same for $X^-$)

Comment: @Heriberto I did not intend any relationship to positive or negative numbers, but rather made those notation choices to reference "*those elements we might want to add*" and "*those elements we might want to remove.*"  In words, the sets in the equivalence class of $X$ are able to be described as $X$ having added some finite collection of elements and having removed some other finite collection of elements.

Comment: @JMoravitz oh I understand, thank you very much :D

Answer (score 1):

You have to prove that $T\setminus V$ and $V\setminus T$ are both finite given that $T\setminus U; etc.$ are all finite.

Let $x \in T\setminus V$ then $x \in T$ . Now either $x \in U$ or $x\not \in U$.  If $x \in U$ we have $x \not \in V$ so $x\in U\setminus V$.  But if $x \not \in U$ we have $x \in T \setminus U$.  So $x \in U \setminus V$ or $x \in T\setminus U$.  So $x \in (U\setminus V)\cup (T\setminus U)$.

So $T\setminus V \subseteq (U\setminus V)\cup (T\setminus U)$ which is the union of two finite sets.

Now... you should have a theorem that the union of two finite subsets is finite so $(U\setminus V)\cup (T\setminus U)$ is finite.

And you should have a theorem that a subset of a finite set is finite.  So $T\setminus V$ is finite.

ANd proving $V\setminus T$ is finite is identically proven.